# What's the simplest set of JVM GC parameters for a server app?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

What's the most commonly used set of GC parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really on-topic.  Either way, you should post everything below the line as an answer to your question.  You can answer your own questions!

Comment: icms is not recommended on any modern system (more than 1 core) due to the single threaded nature of the init mark phase and how it is scheduled between scavenges in icms mode

Comment: Also you should have those logs on always not just in test and blanket statement of a 6g heap is fairly meaningless, eg impact of compressedoops

Comment: I made an incorrect statement and deleted it.

Comment: To follow up on @JonBright's comment, what you need to do here is (a) rephrase the bit above the line as an objective question (eg "What are good garbage collection settings for Sun's JVM when running a server application?"), then post the bit below the line as an answer. Then wait two days to see if anyone can improve on your answer, and accept whatever the best answer is, whether it's yours or not.

Comment: Done.. I've split the Q and A

Answer (score 0):

The question as stated is too vague to answer sanely.  It depends on your workload, requirements, and goals.

In general, I would start with -Xmx (amount of ram you need) g, and -XX:UseCompressedOops.  Beyond that, make a test case.  Make changes *one at a time* and **measure** their effect on *your own workload*.

Answer (score 0):

The question really is very vague, AFAIK there is no one-size-fits-all set of settings that can be used for all/ most applications. Btw, unless I am mistaken, JDK 6 onwards, the JVM also has a limited capability to tune itself anyways. The steps you could take are:

step 1. put in some Xmx and MaxPermSize if you "know" your application will need more than the default.
step 2. Run app and watch jstat. Proceed to step 3 if GC pattern is unsatisfactory
step 3. Tune one setting at a time based on your observation.
step 4. Repeat - go to step 2 :-)

That's the only way I have seen tuning work. If you are using a product (like Weblogic, Websphere), the provider may recommend some basic settings that you could start with, but generally, you would want to start with the default ones.

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

I thought I'd share some settings that have worked for the server apps I've tuned in the past. These have been with Sun/Oracle JDK 6 (at the time of this writing).

This is probably the most commonly used set of GC params. Of course, the settings depend heavily on the nature of your application - object life, allocation rates, complexity of refs/pointers etc. If your experience has been any different please share them.

---

Basic settings. Min and max heap are the same. Assumes 64 bit machine. Heaps larger than 4-6g will require careful tuning and testing. 6g is not mandatory
    `-server -Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Option A (Parallel collector): High throughput, batch oriented work. Noticable periodic pauses.
    `-XX:+UseParallelGC`

Option B (CMS): Lower throughput, lower latency, continuous processing. Frequent unnoticable micro-pauses, rare long pauses.
    `-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250 -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled`

Additional monitoring during UAT/SAT/Pre-production. View this log using [HPJmeter](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPJMETER) or [GCViewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html).
    `-verbose:gc -Xloggc:my_gc_output.hprof -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails`

---

Cheers!

Comment: Well iCMS is not being recommended [anymore](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/really_icms_really), especially since most servers have multiple cores/threads.